# pygtk spinbutton "greek" floating point

Tags: python, sqlite, pygtk

I'm trying to use the data collected by a form I to a sqlite query. In this form I've made a spin button which gets any numeric input (ie. either`2,34` or `2.34`) and sends it in the form of `2,34` which python sees as `str`.

I've already tried to `float()` the value but it doesn't work. It seems to be a locale problem but somehow `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` is unsupported (says WinXP).
All these happen even though I haven't set anything to greek (language, locale, etc) but somehow Windows does its magic.

Can someone help?

PS: Of course my script starts with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` so as to have anything in greek (even comments) in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, WinXP supports `setlocale` just fine.

If you want to do locale-aware conversions, try using `locale.atof('2,34')` instead of `float('2,34')`.

Comment: It worked fine. I had to add the `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` on top of the script... Many thanks